# Why do small start-ups provide internships?

Tags: internship, startup

I have seen a lot of intern job at small start-ups at Angel list and other job boards. I think since they are small start-ups, they generally don't have enough resources and time to train students. So, Why are they providing intern job? Do they look for student who have good knowledge and experience and will be work for them at lost costs in the form of internship?

Comment: cost-efficient, eagerness of learning and ready to accept challenges.

Answer (score 5):

I think the main attraction of an intern is that they do not cost a lot of money. For a fraction of the price of a full employee you have someone working for you. In addition, interns tend to be younger, and thus less likely to have family obligations, making it easier for them to devote a lot of time to the company.

Of course, this is only an advantage if the intern can be productive without a lot of supervision. If not, the intern will swallow up an enormous amount of time. The trick therefore is to select only the best students. In addition, quickly letting go of an intern if things don't work out is probably something that happens a lot.

Comment: In some cases the school may actually pay for part or all of their salary while on internship as well.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of several reasons:

1. **Give something back.**  They create/contribute to Open Source Software,
   post blogs that help others in their field, etc. Giving an inexperienced person some experience is a good thing. Also, the founders may recall their internship at a larger company where they were not allowed to do any significant work.
2. **Screen Potential Candidates** You're right. They do lack resources. An internship can be a less expensive resource, but can also limit the risk of hiring the wrong person. That can be very risky to anyone with limited funds.
3. **Different Perspective** If the company has a lot of experienced members, getting someone still in college can offer different perspectives if they're willing to listen.
4. **Side Projects** Many companies have those side projects that just never get done because everyone is working on the big stuff. Sometimes this could be for internal use (e.g. Automate the build even more).

As an intern, I would sacrifice quality over quantity of mentorship. What programmer wants a daily meeting over formatting old code when you can get some direction on your own project? You can get some help when there is a real problem. The general over-site by an experienced developer as you work on a meaningful project is priceless.